# Why does my app send three UDP packets when I tell it to send one?

Tags: sockets, winapi, udp, boost-asio, msys2

**(Update below.)**

My simple program should send **just one** UDP packet (shouldn't it?), but WireShark shows a burst of 3 identical packets, and the receiver displays 2.

How do I make it send just one? Surely apps have control over this, and not every app is doing this. What am I missing?

On the other hand, this could be a useful feature in some situations: is there a way to make it two or four?

```
//
// How many messages does this send out?
//
// g++ -std=c++20 howmany.cpp -o howmany.exe -lws2_32
//
// nc -u -p 15000 -l
//

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using namespace std;

namespace asio = boost::asio;
using udp = asio::ip::udp;

static constexpr string localBindAddr{"10.0.0.53"};

void HowManyMsgs()
    {
    asio::io_context ioCtxt;
    
    udp::endpoint localEP{ asio::ip::address::from_string(localBindAddr), 15000};
    udp::socket skt{ioCtxt, localEP};
    //udp_socket_await skt{ioCtxt, localEP};
    skt.set_option(udp::socket::reuse_address(true));
    //skt.set_option(asio::ip::unicast::hops(7)); // TTL

    udp::endpoint dest{ asio::ip::address::from_string("10.0.0.140"), 15000};
    string hello{"Hello there destination.\n"};
    size_t nSent = skt.send_to(asio::const_buffer{hello.data(), hello.size()}, dest);
    cout << "Sent once: " << nSent << " bytes to " << dest;
    sleep(1);
    }


int main()
    {
    HowManyMsgs();
    return 0;
    }
```

Wireshark:

```
No. Time    Source  Destination Protocol    Length  Info
65  1.537746    10.0.0.53   10.0.0.140  UDP 67  15000 → 15000 Len=25
66  1.537755    10.0.0.53   10.0.0.140  UDP 67  15000 → 15000 Len=25
67  1.537772    10.0.0.53   10.0.0.140  UDP 67  15000 → 15000 Len=25
```

Receiver:

```
# nc -u -p 15000 -l
Hello there destination.
Hello there destination.
```

I'm running it under boost::asio on win32 (msys2.org /mingw64).

---

**Update:**  This seems to be an artifact of VMWare Workstation's network stack. I run the app from my VM host machine and it sends messages to the VM guest, also running on my machine, with a *bridged* network connection.  When I switch off my VM guest and send it to a different machine on the LAN, **it only sends one packet.**  With the vm guest back on, I get four identical packets apparently sent out to the other machine on the LAN. So the VMWare network adapter is playing the key role here.  I'm still interested in why this is happening, but the adapter configuration(s) seems to be the domain.

Comment: With this code, there should only be 1 UDP packet sent and received, unless the destination IP is a broadcast/multicast IP. If that is not the case, then have you looked at the *details* of each packet in Wireshark to see what *flags*, etc are on them?

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. WireShark shows each packet identical, every single byte.

Comment: Considering your update, I'd move the question (or post a better/separate one) to serverfault.se or something like that